# will firebase triggers fire when running locally?

Tags: firebase, triggers, emulation

I have a firebase functions project that connects to a firebase database in the cloud. If I write a database trigger in my firebase functions, and I emulate those functions locally, will the trigger fire? I mean, because the database is running on the cloud, does it even know about my locally running trigger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the local emulator doesn't work that way.  The only way you can trigger a database function with the emulator is through the command prompt you're provided with.

Comment: Thanks Doug, that saves me potential hours of useless troubleshoot.

Comment: What command prompt? How do you do this?

Comment: @NickJ https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-shell